# Find row in pandas dataframe with matching sequence over several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of varying size, for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
                   columns=['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
```

and a list `li = [5,6]` which I know should be somewhere in the dataframe exactly in its sequence in columns A2 and A3.

I can find that row via

```
mask = (df['A2'] == li[0]) & (df['A3'] == li[1])
```

but I am looking for a more general solution for if the column names and the number of columns change.

I know that we have list `in_ = [2,3]` of variable length and know it must be columns `'A'+str(in_)` that we find `li` in (always of the same length as `in_`). I want to return the row number or index, how can I do that?

Then I want to proceed to extract the value from column `A1` based on the matching other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the columns, perform the comparison and aggregate with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
li = [5,6]
in_ = [2,3]

cols = [f'A{i}' for i in in_]

mask = df[cols].eq(li).all(axis=1)
```

Or, if there is a chance that values in `in_` do not match existing columns, rather [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mask = df.reindex(columns=cols).eq(li).all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: How is the fist option with `df[cols]` different to the second `df.reindex(columns=cols)`? They both do exactly the same when I tested them, also when there were not matchs at all.

Comment: Try with `in_ = [2,7]`, the first option raises an error, the second one gives all False ;)